# How can I count total occurences correctly and save them afterwards in the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, duplicates

So I want to count the total occurences of the attributes year and id and then save them under a new key entry. However, I have only managed to reduce my array and find a solution for counting the entries, but not being able to "merge" the count with the array.
I count by stringifying the id and year, which helps me identify total counts but since js saves the counter as object and the keys are stringified I cannot add the counter to my original array.
This is what I have so far:

```
const keys_to_keep = ["year", "id"];
  const reduceData = (unprocessedData) => unprocessedData.map(entry => keys_to_keep.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = entry[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {}));
  const newData = reduceData(data);

// count where id and year the same:
counter = {}
  newData.forEach(function (obj) {
    var key = JSON.stringify(obj)
    counter[key] = (counter[key] || 0) + 1
  })
```

My array and its entries have this structure:

[{ year: 1994, id: 123 },

{ year: 1994, id: 123 },

{ year: 1998, id: 124 }]

And I want it to look like this, with the count incorporated:

[{ year: 1994, id: 123, count: 2 },

{ year: 1994, id: 123, count: 2 },

{ year: 1998, id: 124, count: 1 }]

Can anyone help me to achieve this :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative could be reducing first to identify the counts and then with the `Array.prototype.map` function create a new array with the desired `count` field.

*O(n)* time complexity, if we want to make it more "exact" *O(2n)*.

```js
const array = [{ year: 1994, id: 123 },{ year: 1994, id: 123 },{ year: 1998, id: 124 }];
const keys = ["year", "id"];
const toKey = obj => keys.map(key => obj[key]).join("_")

const counts = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
  const key = toKey(e);
  acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = array.map((e) => ({...e, count: counts[toKey(e)]}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```